# Self study question on Confidence Interval

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

I am attempting a self study question on confidence interval. My answer worked out to be $20.4 \pm 1.411$. However, the model answer appeared to be $20.4 \pm 1.486$. I am pretty confidence that I am correct. I'd appreciate if anyone could give me some advice and validation please?

***Question***

> The owner of a big egg farm wants to estimate the mean number of eggs laid per chicken. A sample of 25 chickens shows they laid an average of 20.4 eggs per month with a standard deviation of 3.6 eggs per month. Assume the number of eggs laid per chicken per month has a normal distribution. Construct a 95% confidence interval estimate for the population mean number of eggs laid per chicken per month.

***Attempt***

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *almost* correct.
If you had a larger sample of chicken, your attempt would have been correct. However, even though you report normality, you could still adjust for your smaller sample size by using a different distribution.

- What distribution is used for small sample sizes?

When you use the appropriate formula for CIs built from that distribution, you will find that you need a slightly different critical value, which will result in a slightly wider CI.

Answer (score 2):

After taking into consideration @jona's comments, I managed to work out the answer to be the following:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the estimated standard deviation means you use a t-interval. Unfortunately, using pivotal quantities as a way to construct intervals is usually not taught at this level. (I say unfortunately because framing it that way makes it pretty obvious why it must be $t$ and not $z$.)